# Electron: do I need to import libraries in HTML instead of javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, import, electron

I'm learning Electron, creating a simple 3D visualiser based on three.js.

I stumbled upon an issue: the guide I'm following ([here](https://medium.com/@sharadghimire5551/getting-started-with-three-js-and-electron-js-9ae49b1d3f59)) copypastes the three.js library inside the project directory and includes it in the main HTML file with a script tag.

Coming from a Python background this strikes me as very annoying since:

1. I'd need to manually copypaste this into every project that requires three.js;
2. If I want to use a different version of the library I have to copypaste it again.

Is there an alternate way to import three.js that doesn't require me to directly type its path in the HTML file? Or is there a good reason why imports are done this way? I tried looking for a similar answer but couldn't find any, maybe I don't know exactly what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour isn't unique to Electron. Whether you're in a web browser or in the renderer process of an Electron app, using `<script>` tags is the barebones vanilla way to import client-side JavaScript onto a web page. This is in contrast to server-side Node.js, where you can directly `npm install` any package in the registry, and import it using `require`.

To get around this limitation and harness the power of modules, front-end developers use tools such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/modules/) to bundle their code to be compatible with web browsers (maybe the ["Why webpack"](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/why-webpack/) page in their docs can provide even more context).